# Debugging Python inside Docker with Visual Studio 2022

Tags: python, docker, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2022

VS Code can apparently debug Python code running on Docker.

Visual Studio 2022 can debug .NET code running on Docker ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/edit-and-refresh?view=vs-2022 ).

Is there a way to debug Python code running on Docker with Visual Studio 2022?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/edit-and-refresh?view=vs-2022) you included states:

> Supported project types include web app, console app, and Azure Function targeting .NET Framework and .NET Core.

Since Python doesn't meet these requirements, I don't think it is possible.  In addition, one of the first steps you must do when creating the project is to enable Docker, which isn't even an option for a Python project, further leading me to believe its not possible.

It seems that [*Visual Studio Code* appears to be able to do this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/debug-python).